# getSupportActionBar() throws NPE when using appcompat-v7 22.2.1 or newer

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, android-appcompat

I have an app using the below main theme in values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
  <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
  <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/tabtextcolor</item>
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_blue</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_darker_blue</item>
  <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="background">@color/primary_blue</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/primary_blue</item>
    <item name="icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Widget.Carrental.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Widget.Carrental.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Carrental.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
 <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
 <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
 <item name="android:alpha">1</item>
</style>

<style name="tabtextcolor" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
 <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
 <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
</style>
```

All this works fine when I use appcompat-v7 22.2.1 on Kitkat and Lollipop.

I had to add a compile dependency, which had the below theme in values/style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme.Transparent.Base" />

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Transparent.Base" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

And these in values-21/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
  <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
  <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme.Transparent.Base">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Now when I try to run my app, it fails with NPE in the code

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Here is the NPE;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
```

I made sure all the activity classes extend AppCompatActivity but I still got the same NPE. So then I commented the below fields in the dependency library's theme.

```
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

This time my app didn't fail with NPE but I see this message in the logcat when the control passes on to the code in the dependency library.

```
I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
```

Answer (score 0):

i think ,if u set

```
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

u need setSupportActionBar(uToolbar).
if u could't use toolbar,u can try

```
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
```

Comment: I already tried adding `<item name="windowActionBar">true</item>` . I also commented out the two fields in the dependency library but that is causing the `AppCompatDelegate` message